# Error to test a call function onClick react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have the following component and the following test. This test is failing even though the function was mocketed. I'd like know how I should fix it. "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.1" and "react": "^18.2.0".

```
import { useCalculator } from "./hooks/useCalculator";

export const CalculatorApp = () => {
  const { displayNumber, operation, display, answer, reset } = useCalculator();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <p>Calculator - React</p>
        <div className="calculator">
          <div aria-label="display">{displayNumber}</div>

          <div className="calculator__keys">
            <button
              onClick={() => operation("addition")}
              aria-label="addition"
            >
              +
            </button>
            ...
            <button aria-label="seven" onClick={() => display(7)}>7</button>
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

TEST

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { CalculatorApp } from "../src/CalculatorApp.jsx";

describe("Component test <CalculatorApp/>", () => {

  const mockOperation = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => jest.clearAllMocks());

  test("should call a matematical operation", () => {
    render(<CalculatorApp />);

    const selectedOperation = screen.getByLabelText("addition");
    fireEvent.click(selectedOperation);

    expect(mockOperation).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockOperation).toHaveBeenCalledWith("addition");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock the hook to check if the function has been called or not. Currently, you are just creating a mock function (mockOperation) without assigning it your hook.

Add below code in your test file -

```
import * as calculator from "./hooks/useCalculator";

// inside test block
const mockOperation = jest.fn();
jest.spyOn(calculator, 'operation').mockImplementation(() => ({operation: mockOperation}));

// your test code
// ...

// now you can write your assertions
expect(mockOperation).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(mockOperation).toHaveBeenCalledWith("addition");
```